# How to push the data from server side to swing client automatically?

Tags: java, swing, client-side, server-side

Hi i am new for desktop client app. My client side is Java swing and server-side is restlet restful service. I want to push the data from server side to my java swing client automatically for the features like notification, alerts...

Does any one help me out that how to achieve this functionality in this technologies

Answer (score 1):

I would say client should ask server from time to time (e.g. every second) asking whether there are some alerts, notifications etc. on the server.

Comment: If i calling request from client side for every second, will it make performance issues?

Comment: You can define the time interval to decrease performance and make the request processing as fast as possible. An alternative approach would be to mregister somehow all clients but you would need to organize sessions with expiration time etc. and store all sessions on server. Actually it depends on amount of clients and amount of stored info.

Comment: Thanks stan. actually I have worked on flex and JSP. they are supports few api like activemq,cometd, etc. I would expect like that. does any api supports for java swing?